# Expression of type Pointer[Float] doesn't conform to expected type Pointer[Float] in Scala

Tags: java, scala, bridj

I am new to Scala and I have been trying to use library bridj implemented in Java.
Here is the code (allocateFloats is a method in class org.bridj.Pointer)

```scala
import org.bridj.Pointer
import org.bridj.Pointer._

class EstimatingPi {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val n: Int = 1024
    val aPtr : Pointer[Float] = allocateFloats(n)
  }
}
```

This would result in "Expression of type Pointer[Float] doesn't conform to expected type Pointer[Float]". But if I don't specify the type of the aPtr as shown below, the code compiles.

```scala
    val aPtr = allocateFloats(n)
```

I tried to find the solution online but the questions are mostly like "Expression of type someClass[T1] doesn't conform to expected type someClass[T2]". But in my case, they are the same type.
I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of them is probably a `java.lang.Float`.  You probably would need to

```
val aPtr: Pointer[java.lang.Float] = allocateFloats(n)
```

If it is not obvious from the `allocateFloats` documentation, you can find out what type it is by doing something like

```
allocateFloats(0).getClass.getName
```

which will give you the full name with a `[L` before and `;` after, e.g.

```
[Ljava.lang.Float;
```